# how do i plot the candles without running into this specific error?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i tried a lot of methods to solve the error but i cannot seem to be able to solve it. i'm trying to plot a heiken ashi chart but i ran into this error "Cannot call 'plotcandle' with argument 'title'='CColor'. An argument of 'series color' type was used but a 'const string' is expected", i am a beginner i do not understand what the error insunate. how do i solve it?

```
//@version=5
indicator("HA")

// Heiken Ashi

Open = (open[1] + close[1])/2
Close = (open + high + low + close)/4
High = math.max(high, math.max(open, high))
Low = math.min(low, math.max(open, high))

CColor = if Close > Open
    color.lime
else
    color.red

plotcandle(Open, High, Low, Close, CColor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells that you are passing `color` to the `title` argument.

The forth argument of `plotcandle()` is `title` and not `color`.

> plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title, color, wickcolor, editable,
> show_last, bordercolor) → void

If you don't want to give it a title and assign a color to it, you can do it like this:

```
plotcandle(Open, High, Low, Close, color=CColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

script as below

```
//@version=5
indicator("HA")

// Heiken Ashi

Open = (open[1] + close[1])/2
Close = (open + high + low + close)/4
High = math.max(high, math.max(open, high))
Low = math.min(low, math.max(open, high))

CColor = Close > Open ? color.lime :color.red

plotcandle(Open, High, Low, Close, color = CColor)
```